How to upgrade Azure Win11 Multi-session 21H2 AVD VM to latest version?
I have an old Azure VM running W11 Multi-session 21H2 and I would upgrade it to 23H2 (latest version at the moment).
I'm not able to apply any upgrade and Windows Update doesn't show any feature update (it shows Cumulative Updates and others packages only).
Seems to be not possible
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/windows/in-place-system-upgrade
What's your opinion?
Thank you

see  Use Azure Update Manager to update your Azure Stack HCI, version 23H2 (preview). If you are not using Azure Stack HCI, version 23H2 (preview), then you cannot perform an in-place upgrade.

I don't use Azure Stack HCI. Must I create a new vm and create a move data? That's incredible...

Give it a shot.
